# i'm trying to wrrite a regex which will be in the form of - [alphabets] or [alphabets than space/hyphen then number/alphabets]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a regex which will accept which start with alphabets and if thers any number than it should be after space and hyphen only. heres what I written.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[ -]+[a-zA-z0-9]+
```

its accepting: `test-123`, `test 123`, but not accepting only alphabet like test. it should not accept test123 like this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the `[ -]+[a-zA-z0-9]+` part optional by grouping the suffix with `()` and adding a `?` to make it optional.

You will also need to add the end of line/string `$` to make sure that nothing else is allowed.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+([ -]+[a-zA-z0-9]+)?$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Wvj8wPKTJe-4lUmi)

[image: Regular expression visualization]